# WordPress Front End Posting

Tags: wordpress, redirect, frontend, custom-post-type

I am attempting to create a front-end form for a template page and am using the following code. The code works allows the post to be submitted to the custom post type however, it allows the form to be submitted with no data in the fields. Also, I can't figure out how to get the redirect to work correctly.

http://pastebin.com/ts4dmW6A

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have the form handler inside functions.php or in a plugin rather than the template. If you use a hook you can then handle any form submissions there. Action field would determine which hook should be called.

More details can be found here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)